# Multiple custom plugins in TouchUI RTE in AEM not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, aem, color-picker, rte

I tried adding two custom plugins in TouchUI RTE (Image plugin and colorpicker plugin ). if I add either of the one plugin's to RTE, that works fine but when having both together, only color picker plugin appears.

Plugin links:
[http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/01/aem-6-sp1-touchui-richtext-editor-color-picker-plugin.html](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-rich-text-editor-rte-browse-insert-image.html)

http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-rich-text-editor-rte-browse-insert-image.html

I need both the plugins in RTE, Could you please suggest an appropriate approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The components don't work together because components are overriding one to another: `CUI.rte.ui.ToolkitRegistry.register("cui", ExperienceAEM.ToolkitImpl);`

To achieve what you want:

- Remove the custom EAEMCuiToolbarBuilder and EAEMDialogManager classes, instead extending `CUI.rte.ui.cui.CuiToolbarBuilder` and `CUI.rte.ui.cui.CuiDialogManager` directly e.g. `CUI.rte.ui.cui.CuiDialogManager = new Class({ extend: CUI.rte.ui.cui.CuiDialogManager, ... });`
- Remove the EAEMToolkitImpl class and the line `CUI.rte.ui.ToolkitRegistry.register("cui", EAEMToolkitImpl);` as it seems no longer necessary
- Place the colorpicker and image insert plugins into different GROUP names, so that they dont collide when `CUI.rte.plugins.PluginRegistry.register(GROUP, EAEMColorPickerPlugin);` is called.
- Change calls of `this.superClass._getUISettings(options)` and `this.superClass.create.call(this, dialogId, config)` to `this.inherited(arguments)`

Reference: http://experience-aem.blogspot.com.uy/2015/09/aem-61-touch-ui-rich-text-editor-rte-browse-insert-image.html

Comment: Thanks. It was really useful.